# SQL - Multiple Values from the same table (many to one)

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a query that will return values from one table that are in rows as columns (many to one).  I am using Oracle SQL Developer.  For example:

```
    Table1 = WI
    Table2 = VAL
    Key = File
```

The WI table has the main record.  The VAL table has a separate row for each field in the main record.

```
WI
File1 | Type | Date
File2 | Type | Date

VAL
File1 | Field1 | Value
File1 | Field2 | Value
File1 | Field3 | Value
File2 | Field1 | Value
File2 | Field3 | Value
```

I am looking to return:

```
WI.File1 | WI.Type | VAL.Value (Field1) | VAL.Value (Field2) | VAL.Value (Field3)
```

I don't want to exclude records that are Null in VAL.  There will always be a File to File relationship across the tables.  If the value is not used in the record the Field won't be in VAL.

So revisiting the layout above with values:

```
WI
File1 | New | 09/12/2019
File2 | Old | 09/10/2019

VAL
File1 | Amount | 10
File1 | Process| Yes
File1 | Name | Matt
File2 | Amount | 15
File2 | Name | Tom
```

Desired Result:

```
File  | Type | Amount | Process | Name
-----------------------------------------
File1 | New  |10      | Yes     | Matt
File2 | Old  |15      |         | Tom
```

How can I get my desired results?

Comment: What is your rdbms? Sql Server, postgres, oracle? What version?  Google for `PIVOT` for your rdbms

Comment: From the SQL tag guidance: Questions should include **code examples**, table structure, sample data, and **a tag for the DBMS implementation** (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used.

Comment: This looks to be a basic PIVOT query (of which there are a number of here). Is the number of possible field names in Table 2 known/unlikely to change? If so, you can hard-code the values; otherwise, you're likely looking into dynamic SQL.

Comment: I would hard code the values from Table 2.  In reality there are probably 50-100 values for each file.  I usually want to return a specific set of 3 or so.  I am using Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: The possible value of the 'Field' column are only 'Amount', 'Process' and 'Name' or are there many of them? In the first case you can simply use a left outer join (3 times). Otherwise, I suggest a pivot.

Comment: Multiple left outer joins worked wonders.  Thank you so much.  I will look into pivots as well just to educate myself in case that makes sense in the future.  I was trying a single join which was the issue.